# How can I make Email field not-required when I manually create a user from WordPress Admin Panel?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

I am trying to add some users who do not have any emails. I want them to log in with username. And I will create their account from WordPress admin panel. How can I make the email field not required. TIA.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer,

```
// This will suppress empty email errors when submitting the user form
add_action('user_profile_update_errors', 'my_user_profile_update_errors', 10, 3 );
function my_user_profile_update_errors($errors, $update, $user) {
    $errors->remove('empty_email');
}

// This will remove javascript required validation for email input
// It will also remove the '(required)' text in the label
// Works for new user, user profile and edit user forms
add_action('user_new_form', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
add_action('show_user_profile', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
function my_user_new_form($form_type) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('#email').closest('tr').removeClass('form-required').find('.description').remove();
        // Uncheck send new user email option by default
        <?php if (isset($form_type) && $form_type === 'add-new-user') : ?>
            jQuery('#send_user_notification').removeAttr('checked');
        <?php endif; ?>
    </script>
    <?php
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('user_profile_update_errors', 'my_user_profile_update_errors', 10, 3 );
function my_user_profile_update_errors($errors, $update, $user) {
    $errors->remove('empty_email');
}
add_action('user_new_form', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
add_action('show_user_profile', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);
function my_user_new_form($form_type) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('#email').closest('tr').removeClass('form-required').find('.description').remove();
        // Uncheck send new user email option by default
        <?php if (isset($form_type) && $form_type === 'add-new-user') : ?>
            jQuery('#send_user_notification').removeAttr('checked');
        <?php endif; ?>
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for contributing an answer. This is just a note to help you improve your answers. To help future users better understand your answer please provide an explanation with your code blocks. For example, you could explain why your solution works, or how your approach is different from other answers.